# AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'plot'

Tags: python

I am using python 3.6 and a learner.  Below is a simple code of a sin wave.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 

x = np.linspace(-10 , 10, 100)
y = np.sin(x) 
plt.plot(x, y, marker="x")
```

I am receiving the error "AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'plot'"  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the complete error message? Did you really type this code or used something else, e.g. `import matplotlib as plt `?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Have you installed matplotlib properly? I added an extra line to your code to show the plot. This code works properly in Visual Studio after installing the matplotlib library.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 

x = np.linspace(-10 , 10, 100)
y = np.sin(x) 
plt.plot(x, y, marker="x")
plt.show()
```

Comment: @mark one missing part of the code was plt.show(). Anyway for some reason I am not getting the said error.  Thanks

Answer (score 22):

Try this simple step.

use pyplot using below import statement when importing matplotlib library.

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`