# AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'get_data_path'

Tags: python, matplotlib, xlwings

I am using `xlwings` for running a macro from Excel to plot histogram using python matplotlib but I get the following error when trying to run the python code to plot the histogram from excel:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "c:\users\adel.moustafa\dashboard\main.py", line 7, in <module>

    from Modules import Plotter

  File "c:\users\adel.moustafa\dashboard\Modules\Plotter.py", line 6, in <module>

    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  File "C:\Users\adel.moustafa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 887, in <module>

    cbook._get_data_path("matplotlibrc"),

    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "C:\Users\adel.moustafa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 559, in _get_data_path

    return Path(matplotlib.get_data_path(), *args)

                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'get_data_path'
```

This only happens when I try to run the python code from excel using macro, however if run the same code from `Pycharm IDE` it works fine and no error is produced.
I have looked for this error and what it means and reach the conclusion of that the error source may be due to conflict of `matplotlib` versions (one installed using conda and the other using pip). so I have completely removed install `anaconda` distribution using this [guide](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/) after that I uninstall and reinstall `matplotlib` using pip but unfortunately that did not solve the problem. so, I continue to search and found similar posts to my case that advice by using a python virtual environment to solve the problem. so, I have done that but also with no result. finally I completely removed python from my system and reinstalled it but that did not solve the problem either. now, I really don't know what else to do or try!. so if any one could help it would much appreciated.

here is the list of packages installed on my machine

```
Package         Version
--------------- --------
contourpy       1.0.7
cycler          0.11.0
fonttools       4.38.0
kiwisolver      1.4.4
matplotlib      3.6.3
numpy           1.24.1
packaging       23.0
pandas          1.5.3
Pillow          9.4.0
pip             22.3.1
pyparsing       3.0.9
python-dateutil 2.8.2
pytz            2022.7.1
pywin32         305
seaborn         0.12.2
setuptools      65.6.3
six             1.16.0
wheel           0.38.4
xlwings         0.28.9
```

and the python version

```
Python 3.11.1
```

finally here is the posts that I looked at.

1. [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63826975/attributeerror-module-matplotlib-has-no-attribute-get-data-path-on-visual-s)
2. [post2](https://github.com/pykeen/pykeen/issues/505)
3. [post3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47324756/attributeerror-module-matplotlib-has-no-attribute-plot)
4. [post4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67269112/matplotlib-pyplot-has-no-attribute-get-data-path)
5. [post5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66868188/how-to-solve-this-python-attributeerror-module-matplotlib-has-no-attribute-g)